# HasChanged Not Working in Backbone 1.1.2

Tags: backbone.js

**CodePen**: http://codepen.io/opnsrce/pen/hclaH

**Expected behavior**: You should only be able to highlight one item at a time.

Current Behavior: You can highlight multiple items

**Cause**: HasChanged returns true when checked by the controller during the `change` event.

When I run this code with Backbone 0.9.2 it works. When I use 1.1.2 it doesn't.

Did something fundamentally change in the way `hasChanged` works between those two versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the desired functionality. A model's `changed` attributes change each time the model itself is `set`. So until you `set` a model multiple times it will hold onto its changes. The code you've set up here would work if that hash of changes cleared out when a different model was selected. What is actually happening is that as soon as you set a model to `isSelected` it will always have `isSelected == true` and `hasChanged('isSelected')`, so it will never pass the condition to set `isSelected` to `false`.

One way to accomplish what you're looking for is to change your collection method to this:

```
onSelectedChanged: function(modelActive) {
  if(modelActive.get('isSelected') === true){
    this.each(function(model) {
      if (model != modelActive) {
        model.set({isSelected: false});
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Note that I took out `hasChanged` since that was simply confirming that a model had changed at some previous point. Instead I compare the actively selected model with the ones being iterated. We don't want to touch the active one. I also check to see if this method was triggered via the setting of `isSelected` to `true` because if we don't do that, every setting of the iterated models to `false` will trigger this method and cause problems.

The only limitation of this is that you can't select the same item to toggle it off.